# is there a filesystem that a same filepath diverted to different file when different users access it?

Tags: filesystems

I want to access different file when different users access the same
filepath.

For example there is a file path `/path/a.txt` in linux, if
user1 access `/path/a.txt` it actually accesses `/user1/a.txt`; if user2
access `/path/a.txt` it actually accesses `/user2/a.txt`

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head I can think of 4 ways of doing this, but I wouldn't recommend any of them!

1. Use Linux namespaces; inside each per-user namespace bind-mount the per-user file over the top of the base file.
2. Create a per-user chroot environment with the base file symlink'd to the target file
3. Run a FUSE based filesystem and mount this over the top of the base file
4. Have the base file be a named pipe with a daemon process handling read/write to the per-user file.

But *all* of these are complicated to setup and *fragile* and I wouldn't recommend them.  I'm not going into any more depth in how to implement this because if you can't build it then you won't be able to fix it ***WHEN*** it breaks!

In general you should work around the problem in another way in your code (eg use environment variables).

Comment: It wouldn't be fragile on GNU Hurd.  (-:  This is bread-and-butter Hurd translator stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Use a variable to achieve the objective. Suppose you use bash, then for user1, define a variable say cpath in ~/.bashprofile

```
cpath=custom/path1
```

access the file like

```
"/some/path/$cpath/filename" # Quotes important to prevent word splitting
```

for user2, define a variable like

```
cpath=custom/path2
```

access the file like

```
"/some/path/$cpath/filename" #note the same path
```